# What does $\operatorname{d}^3 \vec{v}$ mean when deriving Maxwell's Velocity Distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I'm reading Stocker's Thermodynamics and statistical mechanics. On the subsection "Kinetic theory of the iddal gas", it says something similar to this

> Each particle of the gas has a velocity vector $\vec{v}$, and, on average, there will always be the same number of particles in a certain interval $\operatorname{d}^3 \vec{v}$ of velocity.
>   Let $f(\vec{v})$ be a velocity distribution function, and $N$ the number of particles, we write for the number of particles $\operatorname{d}N(\vec{v})$ in the velocity interval around $\vec{v}$: $$\operatorname{d}N = N f(\vec{v}) \operatorname{d}^3 \vec{v} $$.

Here I got lost, mainly because I have little background on statistics and the like. What does this exactly mean? Is $\operatorname{d}^3 \vec{v}$ a number, and what is it's meaning on the given equation? Thanks, I hope I made myself clear. This book is on the reading material for the Thermodynamics course I'll take next semester.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the integration is over three dimensions of velocity space (the three components of the velocity vector). In this case, when it doesn't have an integral sign in front of it, the text is talking about a small volume ($\mathrm{d}^3v$) of velocity space around the velocity vector $\vec{v}$.

Comment: What integration?

Comment: These quantities are always used inside of integrals. For instance, the mean velocity is:
$$\langle \vec{v} \rangle \equiv \int \vec{v} f(\vec{v}) \operatorname{d}^3v.$$

Comment: Thanks, i get that now. But I can't grasp why is $dN$ calculated that way. Why isn't it simply $N*f(\vec{v})$?

Comment: $N\, f(\vec{v})$ is the number density of particles in velocity space. Since a number is a number density times a volume, the average number of particles in a volume $\operatorname{d}^3 v$ will be $N\, f(\vec{v})\operatorname{d}^3 v$.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a compact notation for indicating a differential element of volume (i.e. a 3 dimensional differential element). Written out in Cartesian coordinates it looks like
$$ \mathrm{d}^3\vec{v} = \mathrm{d} v_x \, \mathrm{d} v_y \, \mathrm{d} v_z \;,$$
so that (again in Cartesian coordinates)
$$ \iiint \dots \mathrm{d}\vec{v} = \iiint \dots \mathrm{d} v_x \, \mathrm{d} v_y \, \mathrm{d} v_z$$
In other context you might see something like
$$ \int_V  \dots \mathrm{d}V $$
with $V$ indicating the volume over which means the same thing.

In addition to being more compact to write, this notation has the advantage of not focing the reader to think in any particular coordinate system. I could just as well have expanded the expression in some other coordinate system as in
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}^3\vec{v} &= \rho \, \mathrm{d}r\, \mathrm{d}\phi \, \mathrm{d} v_z \tag{cylindrical} \\
\mathrm{d}^3\vec{v} &= r^2 \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}r\, \mathrm{d}\phi \, \mathrm{d} \theta \tag{spherical} \;.
\end{align}

Comment: I see, but what does integrating the expression for $dN$ yield, if it is only meaningful in that context?

Comment: Shouldn't be the espression for $d^3 \vec{v}$ in spherical and cylindrical coordinata contain $dv_{x/y/z}$ instead of $dr$?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is if we restrict ourselves to consider velocities in the range, $\vec v + d^3 \vec v$, which is to say, $v_x + dv_x$ and so forth, then the number of particles $dN$ on average is,

$$dN = Nf(\vec v)d^3 \vec v. $$

This makes sense if we think of $d^3\vec v$ as ordinary quantities, but then in order to define $N$, we must perform an integration and treat them as differentials, integrating over velocity space,

$$N = \int Nf(\vec v) d^3\vec v$$

where $d^3\vec v$ indicates integration over the range of values for $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$. You will encounter such integrations in physics often. Using the Fourier transform, you will often find yourself integrating over momentum space, $d^3p$, which simply means over all $p_x, p_y$ and $p_z$.

Another common notation is $\mathrm d\mathbf{x}$ or $\mathrm d \underline{x}$ for example, which simply means integrating over all the components of position. In some cases, one may denote integration over a particular space by $\mathrm d$ followed by the notation for the space.

For example, for a volume $V$, we may denote integration over it using $\mathrm d V$, or for a surface $A$, we may denote integration with $\mathrm d A$. The mathematician's notation is often $\mu_M$ for a manifold or cycle $M$.